# Label propagation in semi-supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, svm, semi-supervised-learning

Suppose we have a set of labeled and unlabeled instances. 70%unlabeled 30% labeled. We apply a semi-supervised algorithm. Let's say we apply S3VM or Laplacian SVM. We use all the data available. When finish training we have a function $f(\mathbf{x})$ that predict the class label. Is it correct now to label the unlabeled samples we have used to train the classifier with this function?

Comment: Related http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3144

Answer (score 1):

First:  S3VM and LapSVM are NOT label propagation algos.

Second: it is never this simple.
For the S3VM , you usually need to know the fraction of (+) labels in the unlabelled set.  It is certainly true for the TSVM in SvmLin.  I don't know if LapSVM will be skewed if the Unlabelled set has a very different balance.

I have a blog post on this

https://charlesmartin14.wordpress.com/2014/11/01/machine-learning-with-missing-labels-part-3-experiments/

Comment: Thanks, it helped me the post. I'm going to update my first post.

Comment: How can I apply feature selection when using TSVM or manifold regularization